# Programa sempre retornando "false"

Tags: prolog

Estou aprimorando minhas habilidades de Prolog, e estou resolvendo um problema do RachaCuca.

Esse é o primeiro que eu tento fazer, e, por algum motivo, ele retorna tudo como falso (O que não deveria). Então gostaria de saber se existe algum **problema estrutural** no meu código, caso não, deve ser apenas alguma coisa errada em alguma afirmativa (o que chequei, mas não achei nada). Segue o código:

```
%%Adicionando biblioteca

cor(amarelo).
cor(azul).
cor(branco).
cor(verde).
cor(vermelho).

motorista(vinicius).
motorista(joao).
motorista(limao).
motorista(carol).
motorista(leo).

destino(amazonas).
destino(bahia).
destino(mato_grosso).
destino(minas_gerais).
destino(parana).

carga(adubo).
carga(carvao).
carga(enxofre).
carga(soda_caustica).
carga(trigo).

placa('AAA-1111').
placa('BBB-2222').
placa('CCC-3333').
placa('DDD-4444').
placa('EEE-5555').

km(50).
km(100).
km(150).
km(200).
km(250).

% Definindo alldiferent 
alldifferent([]).
alldifferent([H|T]):- not(member(H,T)),
                      alldifferent(T).


start:- caminhoes([C1, C2, C3, C4,C5]),
         writeln("\n CAMINHAO 1: ":C1),
         writeln("\n CAMINHAO 2: ":C2),
         writeln("\n CAMINHAO 3: ":C3),
         writeln("\n CAMINHAO 4: ":C4),
         writeln("\n CAMINHAO 5: ":C5).


caminhoes([(COR1, MOTORISTA1, DESTINO1, CARGA1, PLACA1, KM1),
         (COR2, MOTORISTA2, DESTINO2, CARGA2, PLACA2, KM2),
         (COR3, MOTORISTA3, DESTINO3, CARGA3, PLACA3, KM3),
         (COR4, MOTORISTA4, DESTINO4, CARGA4, PLACA4, KM4),
         (COR5, MOTORISTA5, DESTINO5, CARGA5, PLACA5, KM5)]):-

    %%Vamos lidar com os motoristas

    motorista(MOTORISTA1), motorista(MOTORISTA2), motorista(MOTORISTA3),
    motorista(MOTORISTA4), motorista(MOTORISTA5), 
    alldifferent([MOTORISTA1, MOTORISTA2, MOTORISTA3, MOTORISTA4, MOTORISTA5]),

    %%O número 1 fala que Jorge é o motorista do caminhão de placa DDD-4444.
(
(MOTORISTA1==limao,PLACA1=='DDD-4444');
(MOTORISTA2==limao,PLACA2=='DDD-4444');
(MOTORISTA3==limao,PLACA3=='DDD-4444');
(MOTORISTA4==limao,PLACA4=='DDD-4444');
(MOTORISTA5==limao,PLACA5=='DDD-4444')
),

    %%O número 15 fala que Stênio está dirigindo para Minas Gerais.

(
(MOTORISTA1==leo,DESTINO1==minas_gerais);
(MOTORISTA2==leo,DESTINO2==minas_gerais);
(MOTORISTA3==leo,DESTINO3==minas_gerais);
(MOTORISTA4==leo,DESTINO4==minas_gerais);
(MOTORISTA5==leo,DESTINO5==minas_gerais)
),

    %%O 19 fala que Antônio é o motorista do caminhão de placa EEE-5555.

(
(MOTORISTA1==vinicius,PLACA1=='EEE-5555');
(MOTORISTA2==vinicius,PLACA2=='EEE-5555');
(MOTORISTA3==vinicius,PLACA3=='EEE-5555');
(MOTORISTA4==vinicius,PLACA4=='EEE-5555');
(MOTORISTA5==vinicius,PLACA5=='EEE-5555')
),

    %%O número 21 fala que Pedro está ao lado do caminhão que vai para 
    %%o Mato Grosso.

(
(MOTORISTA1==carol,DESTINO2==mato_grosso);
(MOTORISTA2==carol,(DESTINO1==mato_grosso;DESTINO3==mato_grosso));
(MOTORISTA3==carol,(DESTINO2==mato_grosso;DESTINO4==mato_grosso));
(MOTORISTA4==carol,(DESTINO3==mato_grosso;DESTINO5==mato_grosso));
(MOTORISTA5==carol,DESTINO4==mato_grosso)
),

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %%Vamos lidar com as cores 

cor(COR1), cor(COR2), cor(COR3), cor(COR4), cor(COR5), 
alldifferent([COR1, COR2, COR3, COR4, COR5]),

    %%O número 4 diz que o caminhão Vermelho está em algum lugar à esquerda 
    %%do caminhão que vai para o Amazonas.

(
(COR1==vermelho,(DESTINO2==amazonas;DESTINO3==amazonas;DESTINO4==amazonas;DESTINO5==amazonas));
(COR2==vermelho,(DESTINO3==amazonas;DESTINO4==amazonas;DESTINO5==amazonas));
(COR3==vermelho,(DESTINO4==amazonas;DESTINO5==amazonas));
(COR4==vermelho,DESTINO5==amazonas)
),

    %%O número 6 fala que o caminhão Vermelho está em algum lugar entre o 
    %%caminhão que está carregando Enxofre e o caminhão Azul, nessa ordem.

(
(CARGA1==enxofre,COR3==azul,(COR2==vermelho));
(CARGA1==enxofre,COR4==azul,(COR2==vermelho;COR3==vermelho));
(CARGA1==enxofre,COR5==azul,(COR2==vermelho;COR3==vermelho;COR4==vermelho));
(CARGA2==enxofre,COR4==azul,(COR3==vermelho));
(CARGA2==enxofre,COR5==azul,(COR3==vermelho;COR4==vermelho));
(CARGA3==enxofre,COR5==azul,(COR4==vermelho))
),

    %%O número 10 fala que o caminhão Branco está em algum lugar à direita do caminhão Verde.

(
(COR1==verde,(COR2==branco;COR3==branco;COR4==branco;COR5==branco));
(COR2==verde,(COR3==branco;COR4==branco;COR5==branco));
(COR3==verde,(COR4==branco;COR5==branco));
(COR4==verde,COR5==branco)
),

    %%O número 13 fala que o caminhão Amarelo está exatamente à esquerda do 
    %%caminhão que tem 200 mil Km rodados.

(
(COR1==amarelo,KM2==200);
(COR2==amarelo,KM3==200);
(COR3==amarelo,KM4==200);
(COR4==amarelo,KM5==200)
),

    %%O número 17 fala que o veículo Azul está em algum lugar à direita do 
    %%veículo de placa AAA-1111.

(
(PLACA1=='AAA-1111',(COR2==azul;COR3==azul;COR4==azul;COR5==azul));
(PLACA2=='AAA-1111',(COR3==azul;COR4==azul;COR5==azul));
(PLACA3=='AAA-1111',(COR4==azul;COR5==azul));
(PLACA4=='AAA-1111',COR5==azul)
),

    %%O número 20 fala que o caminhão Azul está em algum lugar à 
    %%esquerda do caminhão Branco.

(
(COR5==branco,(COR4==azul;COR3==azul;COR2==azul;COR1==azul));
(COR4==branco,(COR3==azul;COR2==azul;COR1==azul));
(COR3==branco,(COR2==azul;COR1==azul));
(COR2==branco,COR1==azul)
),

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %%Vamos lidar com os destinos


destino(DESTINO1), destino(DESTINO2), destino(DESTINO3), 
destino(DESTINO4), destino(DESTINO5), 
alldifferent([DESTINO1, DESTINO2, DESTINO3, DESTINO4, DESTINO5]),

    %%O número 2 fala que na quarta posição está o caminhão que vai 
    %%para Belo Horizonte.
    %%LEMBRANDO que Belo Horizonte fica em Minas Gerais.

DESTINO4==minas_gerais,

    %%O número 5 fala que o veículo que vai para a região Centro-oeste
    %% está ao lado do caminhão que já rodou 100 mil Km.
    %%LEMBRANDO que o Mato Grosso fica no centro-oeste.

(
(DESTINO1==mato_grosso,KM2==100);
(DESTINO2==mato_grosso,(KM1==100;KM3==100));
(DESTINO3==mato_grosso,(KM2==100;KM4==100));
(DESTINO4==mato_grosso,(KM3==100;KM5==100));
(DESTINO5==mato_grosso,KM4==100)
),

    %%O número 12 fala que quem vai para a região Nordeste está em 
    %%algum lugar à direita do caminhão Vermelho.
    %%LEMBRANDO que a Bahia fica no nordeste.

(
(DESTINO2==bahia,COR1==vermelho);
(DESTINO3==bahia,(COR1==vermelho;COR2==vermelho));
(DESTINO4==bahia,(COR1==vermelho;COR2==vermelho;COR3==vermelho));
(DESTINO5==bahia,(COR1==vermelho;COR2==vermelho;COR3==vermelho;COR4==vermelho))
),

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %%Vamos lidar com as cargas

carga(CARGA1), carga(CARGA2), carga(CARGA3), carga(CARGA4), 
carga(CARGA5), 
alldifferent([CARGA1, CARGA2, CARGA3, CARGA4, CARGA5]),

    %%O número 9 fala que o caminhão de placa DDD-4444 está transportando Soda cáustica.

(
(PLACA1=='DDD-4444',CARGA1==soda_caustica);
(PLACA2=='DDD-4444',CARGA2==soda_caustica);
(PLACA3=='DDD-4444',CARGA3==soda_caustica);
(PLACA4=='DDD-4444',CARGA4==soda_caustica);
(PLACA5=='DDD-4444',CARGA5==soda_caustica)
),

    %%O número 16 fala que o caminhão com Adubo está em algum lugar entre o caminhão
    %%que vai para Bahia e o caminhão com Carvão, nessa ordem.

(
(DESTINO1==bahia,CARGA3==carvao,(CARGA2==adubo));
(DESTINO1==bahia,CARGA4==carvao,(CARGA2==adubo;CARGA3==adubo));
(DESTINO1==bahia,CARGA5==carvao,(CARGA2==adubo;CARGA3==adubo;CARGA4==adubo));
(DESTINO2==bahia,CARGA4==carvao,(CARGA3==adubo));
(DESTINO2==bahia,CARGA5==carvao,(CARGA3==adubo;CARGA4==adubo));
(DESTINO3==bahia,CARGA5==carvao,(CARGA4==adubo))
),

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %%Vamos lidar com as placas

placa(PLACA1), placa(PLACA2), placa(PLACA3), placa(PLACA4), 
placa(PLACA5), 

alldifferent([PLACA1, PLACA2, PLACA3, PLACA4, PLACA5]),

    %%O número 8 fala que em uma das pontas está o caminhão de placa AAA-1111.

(PLACA1=='AAA-1111';PLACA5=='AAA-1111'),

    %%O número 11 fala que o veículo de placa BBB-2222 está ao lado
    %%do veículo mais rodado.

(
(PLACA1=='BBB-2222',KM2==250);
(PLACA2=='BBB-2222',(KM1==250;KM3==250));
(PLACA3=='BBB-2222',(KM2==250;KM4==250));
(PLACA4=='BBB-2222',(KM3==250;KM5==250));
(PLACA5=='BBB-2222',KM4==250)
),

    %%O número 14 fala que o veículo de placa CCC-3333 está exatamente
    %%à direita do veículo de placa DDD-4444.

(
(PLACA1=='DDD-4444',PLACA2=='CCC-3333');
(PLACA2=='DDD-4444',PLACA3=='CCC-3333');
(PLACA3=='DDD-4444',PLACA4=='CCC-3333');
(PLACA4=='DDD-4444',PLACA5=='CCC-3333')
),

    %%O número 18 fala que o caminhão de placa DDD-4444 está ao lado do
    %%caminhão que já rodou 100 mil Km.

(
(PLACA1=='DDD-4444',KM2==100);
(PLACA2=='DDD-4444',(KM1==100;KM3==100));
(PLACA3=='DDD-4444',(KM2==100;KM4==100));
(PLACA4=='DDD-4444',(KM3==100;KM5==100));
(PLACA5=='DDD-4444',KM4==100)
),

    %%O número 22 fala que em uma das pontas está o caminhão de placa EEE-5555.

(PLACA1=='EEE-5555';PLACA5=='EEE-5555'),

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %%Vamos lidar com as quilometragem

km(KM1), km(KM2), km(KM3), km(KM4), km(KM5), 

alldifferent([KM1, KM2, KM3, KM4, KM5]),

    %%O número 3 diz que o caminhão menos rodado está transportando Carvão.

(
(KM1==50,CARGA1==carvao);
(KM2==50,CARGA2==carvao);
(KM3==50,CARGA3==carvao);
(KM4==50,CARGA4==carvao);
(KM5==50,CARGA5==carvao)
),

    %%O número 7 diz que na primeira posição está o caminhão que 
    %%tem 150 mil Km rodados.

KM1==150.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Por favor, estou sem ideias para o que está falhando :(
Quando digito start., ele retorna um "false" ao invés das informações ordenadas, acho que é como se ele concluísse que não é possível.
Uso o SWI prolog, aliás

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema é que você está fazendo comparações de valores concretos com variáveis ainda não instanciadas. O operador `==` só terá sucesso se os termos de ambos os lados já forem iguais, sem nenhuma unificação adicional. Por isso, já na primeira regra ele não consegue achar resultados - pois embora você tenha instanciado `motorista`, você ainda não instanciou `placa`:

```
%%Vamos lidar com os motoristas

motorista(MOTORISTA1), motorista(MOTORISTA2), motorista(MOTORISTA3),
motorista(MOTORISTA4), motorista(MOTORISTA5), 
alldifferent([MOTORISTA1, MOTORISTA2, MOTORISTA3, MOTORISTA4, MOTORISTA5]),

%%O número 1 fala que Jorge é o motorista do caminhão de placa DDD-4444.
(
(MOTORISTA1==limao,PLACA1=='DDD-4444'); % Aqui PLACA1 ainda é uma variável livre
```

Se você mover o "Vamos lidar com as placas" pra antes desse código, ele vai conseguir passar desse ponto. Mas vai falhar no ponto seguinte, pois você ainda não instanciou os destinos...

Isso explica os erros, mas minha sugestão é não fazer dessa forma - pois assim ele vai gerar *todas* as combinações de *todos* os atributos antes de fazer os testes que iriam descartar os resultados inválidos. Em vez disso, faça os testes primeiro - usando `=` em vez de `==` (já que esse operador sim unifica variáveis livres quando possível) - e só no final unifique o que faltar e teste por unicidade. Assim não só o programa funcionará como terminará muito mais rapidamente ([exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/pfAXGF)).

```
%%O número 1 fala que Jorge é o motorista do caminhão de placa DDD-4444.
(
(MOTORISTA1=limao,PLACA1='DDD-4444'); % Aqui PLACA1 ainda é uma variável livre...
                                  % ...mas isso não importa, porque variáveis
                                  % livres podem ser unificadas com qualquer coisa
```